# Word Art effect in Flash Design Studio using ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, actionscript-2

How can I develope word Art effect functinality for run time added test (Like Blue Cotton)?
Please see the given below example [Click Here For Example](http://www.bluecotton.com/studio.html)

1. click on the example link
2. After loading add the Text on T-shirt
3. Write Some Text in side teh added teztfield and make it done.
4. you will find out the Text Effect Popup window in the application
5. click on the Shape, new popup window will come out and it will contain some Word Art effect options,
6. Please select and check the output.

I want to this type effect all / some of them.

Can you help me to get it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no free library available for this. You have to develop an engine in Actionscript which accepts text configuration (text, font, size etc.) and  processes characters in the text. An alternative is to send the configuration to server and do this processing on server side using a library like imagemagick : http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/texteffect/index.php

Comment: Thanks for Answer. But I required client side ActionScript 3.0 development without any server side development / execution dependancy...Please check mentioned example. (BlueCotton)